# Ember Data not storing ID

Tags: mongodb, ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a website using nodejs for server side, emberjs for client side and mongodb for database. I have a page where a user profile is created and saved but the id of the data is stored as undefined unless I refresh. Is there a way atound this?

Comment: I just posted an a question similar to that, I found that by bug is only for the first object that I create, could you confirm that by creating a second test record in your saving process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to see the specific code in order to answer this with certain, but I suspect that you're either not waiting for a response from the server, or you're not passing in the model when you transition to the new route. Ember-data automatically updates when it gets a response from the server.

The general flow should go like this:

1. Send your post request to the server.
2. The server creates the user in Mongodb, and when it gets that object back, it sends it back to the client.
3. On the client, you wait to get the user back from the server, and pass the model into your transitionTo helper.

Here's an example on the Ember side:

```
App.UserCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    createUser: function() {
      var self = this;

      this.get('model')
        .save()
        .then(function() {
          self.transitionToRoute('profile', self.get('model'));
        }, function() {
          alert('User not successfully saved');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Another possible issue is that you're not sending the data back as Ember-data expects. i.e. Your payload should look something like this:

```
{
    user: {
        _id: 'lkj234l23jlk5j4l32j5lk34',
        name: 'Jon Snow'
    }
}
```

And you should let Ember know that it should be using the `_id` instead:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: "_id"
});
```

If this isn't your problem, post some code or give more details.